# Can I update a record in memory like Salesforce does without actually storing into database

Tags: apex

We are trying to build a Unit test mock data framework - which means creating a static pool of data during run time without going as far as to implement System.stubProvider.

So in that scenario, I am trying to implement the update functionality - which means say if the original case has 10 fields specified and the updated version has 3 fields with values, we should only update the 3 fields' values without touching other fields' values.

I am thinking of ways to implement this. One possible solution is to use json to serialize the object into a string. However, since the value equals to null and not provided are actually two different things, I am kind of stuck here for a good solution exception for direct string analysis which can be a big pain.

Any suggestions here?

To make the question more clear, I can put some sample code here:

```
Map<id, Account> accDumps;

updateAccount(Account acc) {
   accDumps.put(acc.Id, acc); //This won't work well since it is just a replacement
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() for this:

```
updateAccount(Account acc) {
   Account storedAcc = accDumps.get(acc.Id);
   Map<sObjectField, Object> values = acc.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
   for(sObjectField field: values.keySet()) {
     storedAcc.put(field, values.get(field));
   }
}
```

Note you don't need to put the record back into the map, since we're updating the record by reference.

This isn't a *perfect* model; if you need to worry about relationship fields, possibly missing records, etc, you'll need some additional error checking.

Comment: Thank you. This is awesome for me. We don't worry about relationship fields for now in our framework, so it should be fine.

Comment: @LanceShi As always, glad to help!

Comment: Any need to worry about formula field values? I am wondering if you would be better off using the [SObject Fabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) approach?

Comment: @PhilW Formulas would only be set from a query or recalculateFormulas. If you don't use either, it's fine. Fabricator works fine, but isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: I'm thinking about the case where you want to mock out queries and DML entirely and have only in-memory objects in unit testing; this is where the fabricator is handy, along side fake IDs. Anyway, it depends on what the OP wants to do in the end with their unit tests...